# How to use Parallel::ForkManager and Capture::Tiny together?

Tags: linux, perl

Below is a simplified example of my problem. Here `exec` should give an error because `xecho` doesn't exist.

**Question**

Is there a way to have `Capture::Tiny` capture the output from `Parallel::ForkManager`?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
    my $pid = $pm->start;
    if (!$pid) {
        no warnings;  # no warnings "exec" is not working
        exec("xecho test");
        $pm->finish;
    }
};

print "$stdout\n";
print "$exit\n";
print "$stderr\n";
```

Comment: what is xecho ?  I suspect that bypasses capture, and Parallel::ForkManager has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @ysth It is just a command that doesn't exist to simulate an error.

Comment: ? but there is no output other than the warning from a failed exec; what are you trying to capture?

Comment: I think you should unsimplify some and show something closer to your real case.  You aren't waiting for the child to finish, for example.

Comment: @ysth Yes, the problem is that I don't get any output when using `parallel::ForkManager`. If that is removed then it will output `file not found` in `$stderr` which is what I want. My exact case is to lunch `ssh` to execute a remote command. I thought I am waiting for the child to finish. But if I am not, then it would explain another problem I have =) How do I make it wait for the child to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to capture output from a child process, but you could use the `run_on_finish` method from [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);
use Data::Dump;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
$pm -> run_on_finish (
  sub {
    my (
        $pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, 
        $core_dump, $data_structure_reference
    ) = @_;

    my $info = ${$data_structure_reference};
    print "Received from child: \n";
    dd $info;
  }
);

my $pid = $pm->start;
if (!$pid) {
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
        sleep 4;
        exec("xecho");
    };
    my $info = {stdout => $stdout, stderr => $stderr, exit=> $exit};
    $pm->finish(0, \$info);
}

print "Master: waiting for child..\n";
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Output:

```
Master: waiting for child..
Received from child: 
{
  exit   => 0,
  stderr => "Can't exec \"xecho\": No such file or directory at ./p.pl line 28.\n",
  stdout => "",
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Can it be extended to also be able to output `$stdout` from the child?